# All Buttons Change Color even one button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The project or app i am making is that there is a sequence of colors everytime you start a new game.
below the color sequence, i have buttons that you need to guess and click to match the color sequence. if you guessed correctly the first button, it should change the background color to the first color of the sequence but the problem is All buttons change color even one button is only clicked.
[image: here is the visual representation of the app]
i can't seem to find a solution on how to change the color on only one button
here is the code:

`

```
//declaring the colors
const colorSequence = [
  { "color":  "#3db44b" },
  { "color":  "#bfef45" },
  { "color":  "#42d3f4" },
  { "color":  "#4263d8" },
  { "color":  "#f68232" },
  { "color":  "#fee118" },
  { "color":  "#e6194a" },
  { "color":  "#f032e6" },
  { "color":  "#921eb3" }
]

function App() { let ctr: number
  const [colors, setColors] = useState<{ color: string }[]>([])
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState<{ color: string }[]>([])
  const [changeColor, setChangeColor] =useState('#451252')
  ctr = 0
  
  //shuffle the color sequence
  const shuffleColors = () => {
    const shuffledColors = [...colorSequence]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((color) => ({ ...color }))

      setColors(shuffledColors)
      shuffleButtons()
  }
  //shuffle the buttons
  const shuffleButtons = () => {
    const shuffledButtons = [...colorSequence]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((color) => ({ ...color }))

      setButtons(shuffledButtons)
  }
  //check Sequence
  const checkSequence = (event: React.MouseEvent, colorCode:string) => {
    console.log(colorCode, colors[ctr].color, ctr)
    if(colorCode === colors[ctr].color){
      const randomColors =  '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2,8)
        setChangeColor(randomColors)
      ctr++
    }
    else{

      ctr = 0
    }

    if(ctr === colors.length){
      alert('Congrats! Good Job!')
      ctr = 0
      shuffleButtons()
      shuffleColors()
    }
  }
  
 
  console.log(colors)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant='contained' onClick={shuffleColors}>New Game</Button>

      <div className = "color-seq">
        {colors.map(color => (
          <div className="color" key={color.color}>
              <div className="square" style={{backgroundColor: color.color}}/>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="color-button">
        {buttons.map(button => (
          <div className="button" key={button.color}>
              <Button 
                variant='contained'
                style={{backgroundColor:`${changeColor}`}}    
                onClick={(e) => {checkSequence( e, button.color )}}>{button.color}
              </Button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

## I can't find any way to fix this problem. How can i change a color of button thats inside a map function without changing all the buttons color in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make component for buttons and color them by thier own state isolatly

sth like this :

```
const colorSequence = [
  { color: "#3db44b" },
  { color: "#bfef45" },
  { color: "#42d3f4" },
  { color: "#4263d8" },
  { color: "#f68232" },
  { color: "#fee118" },
  { color: "#e6194a" },
  { color: "#f032e6" },
  { color: "#921eb3" }
];

interface GuessButtonProps {
  checkSequence: (event: React.MouseEvent, colorCode: string) => string;
  btn: {
    color: string;
  };
  defaultColor: string;
  ctr: number;
}

const GuessButton = ({
  checkSequence,
  btn,
  ctr,
  defaultColor
}: GuessButtonProps) => {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ctr === 0) {
      setButtonColor(defaultColor);
    }
  }, [ctr]);

  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      style={{ backgroundColor: `${buttonColor}` }}
      onClick={(e) => {
        if (ctr < colorSequence.length && buttonColor === defaultColor) {
          let color = checkSequence(e, btn.color);
          if (color) {
            setButtonColor(color);
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      {buttonColor}
    </Button>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState<{ color: string }[]>([]);
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState<{ color: string }[]>([]);
  const [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0);
  const [changeColor, setChangeColor] = useState("#451252");

  const shuffleButtons = () => {
    const shuffledButtons = [...colorSequence]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((color) => ({ ...color }));

    setButtons(shuffledButtons);
  };

  //shuffle the color sequence
  const shuffleColors = () => {
    const shuffledColors = [...colorSequence]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((color) => ({ ...color }));

    setColors(shuffledColors);
    shuffleButtons();
  };
  //shuffle the buttons

  //check Sequence
  const checkSequence = (event: React.MouseEvent, colorCode: string) => {
    let color = null;
    console.log(colorCode, colors[ctr].color, ctr);
    if (colorCode === colors[ctr].color) {
      console.log("correct");
      color = colorCode;
      setCtr((prevState) => {
        if (ctr === colors.length - 1) {
          alert("Congrats! Good Job!");
          shuffleButtons();
          shuffleColors();
          return 0;
        }
        return prevState + 1;
      });
    } else {
      color = null;
      setCtr(0);
    }

    return color;
  };

  console.log(colors);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={shuffleColors}>
        New Game
      </Button>

      <div className="color-seq" style={{ width: 500, height: 250 }}>
        {colors.map((color) => (
          <div
            className="color"
            style={{ width: 40, height: 20 }}
            key={color.color}
          >
            <div
              className="square"
              style={{ width: 40, height: 20, backgroundColor: color.color }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="color-button">
        {buttons.map((btn) => (
          <div className="button" key={btn.color}>
            <GuessButton
              ctr={ctr}
              checkSequence={checkSequence}
              defaultColor={changeColor}
              btn={btn}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Binding element 'btn' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Binding element 'checkSequence' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Comment: I added GuessButtonProps @Jikk

Comment: It does not work. Here is a video of the React App - Color Sequence that im trying to replicate : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-8ee5GF5_gNvRWTuuqhF9sBuoc48F6i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: aha, got it, I'm gonna fix it

Comment: @Jikk  I updated and now its working
please let me know if sth still goes wrong

Comment: it's working but there's one code that is having an error which is this Type '(event: React.MouseEvent, colorCode: string) => string | null' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>, colorCode: string) => string'.
  Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
App.tsx(19, 3): The expected type comes from property 'checkSequence' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & GuessButtonProps'

Comment: @Jikk fixed it and updated

Comment: Thanks everytthing works but the only last problem is that when everything is correct it will not alert 'Congrats' and does not restart and reshuffle the colors

Comment: aha got it ,I'm gonna fix it

Comment: YESS! it's working now. Thank you for staying with me and for your patience. I am new to react and this will be my learning steps... thank you.

Comment: Happy to hear that , wish success for you,
if need any help, you can count on me ;)